# Curve Modifier NURBS path Shape Key animation incompatibility with Unity

Tags: animation, unity

I'm a civil engineering student who's developing an augmented reality app on unity to help other students understand better how structures, such as beams and columns, work under certain load conditions.

I already created a simple 3d model and animation in blender 2.80rc2 that explain how a type of beam deforms under a certain load. In order to do that I've used a curve modifier linked to a nurbs path. After that I created a shape key animation into the cube but that didn't work because every time I did that the object would change positions what screws up the animation.

In order to fix that I created the shape key animation in the nurbs path what gave me the desired animation effect. However unity doesn't like that, it doesn`t recognize the shape key animation.

I was wondering if I could create the same animation effect applying the shape key animation to the cube (what Unity is totally fine with) instead of the nurbs path.

That's not my area of expertise and I'm really struggling with this